# Is there any reason to use Math.pow() with literals rather than the result itself?

Tags: java, formula

I'm currently looking at existing code. There are many methods that have been written to model existing formulas. I stumbled over dozens of instances of code like `Math.pow(10.0D, 3.0D)`, `Math.pow(300.0D, 2.0D)` and also stuff like `1.5D * 1000.0D`.

Now, before I go ahead and replace all these with their respective results (`1000d`, `90000d`, `1500d` for the examples above), I wanted to figure out if there are any good reasons to keep with the original notation?

The only thing that came to my mind is to preserve the resemblance of the code to the modeled formulas. Are there any other reasons I fail to see?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's essentially all about readability. You'll see this sort of code style more commonly when dealing with time, for example:

```
Thread.sleep(5 * 60 * 1000);
```

This style makes it more obvious that the thread will sleep for 5 minutes. When dealing with mathematical formulas, it's common to keep each value of the formula intact so it's obvious what formula is being used and that it is being used correctly.

Comment: Right, so that really seems to be the only reason then. That's what I wanted to know - thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Programmers like to write things out long hand for the sake of readability: knowing, for example, that there are 86400 seconds in a normal day really belongs to attendees of pub quizzes, not programmers.

But that said, I'd be inclined to **not** use `Math.pow` for this.

The chief reason being that it's *probably* not a *compile time evaluable constant expression*, although that *could* depend on the compiler.

You might find that `pow(x, y)` is implemented as `exp(y log x)`: this can "go off" for surprisingly trivial-looking values of `x` and `y` due to a floating point `double` being only accurate to around 15 decimal significant figures.

(Currently the JLS specifies only one `Math.pow` function which takes two `double` arguments. If you were to use integral literals, then the compiler would automatically convert them to `double` types prior to calling the function. It appears that the author is using `double` literals to guard against the possibility of future overloads of `Math.pow` being introduced.)

In your particular cases, I'd consider replacing `Math.pow(300.0D, 2.0D)` with `300.0 * 300.0` and `Math.pow(10.0D, 3.0D)` with `10.0 * 10.0 * 10.0`. But do check that these values are identical to the original ones; and investigate the impact of any discrepancies carefully.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I was wondering if floating point precision might be of relevance here; though from your answer it seems that rather preventing such issues, the use of Math.pow() is more likely to introduce them, if anything.

Comment: Indeed `Math.pow` *might* cause you problems, but do note that arithmetic with floating point integers is exact up to the 53rd power of 2.

Answer (score 3):

It could make it easier to verify that a formula was translated correctly into code. Consider also whether some of these numeric literals should be replaced with named constants to further improve readability. Without knowing the context, it looks a lot of ["magic numbers".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))

Comment: Using some named constants here seems like a good idea indeed. I will try to understand where the formulas are coming from replace literals where possible.